# Change image when clicked (open and close) menu button

Tags: html, menu, onclick, menuitem

**I have a set of menu's visable at**

http://carbonyzed.co.uk/menu/2/

Now when you click the **MENU** button the UL eliment opens, but I also need the menu.png item (the button) to change to a full width version we will call menu_open.png.

**here is the HTML code**

```
<div class="sidebar">
<a href="#" onclick="return showOrHide('menulink');"><div class="logo">TEST IMAGE</div></a>
<ul id="menulink">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Campaigns </a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Links </a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Media </a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Messages </a>           
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Maintenance </a>            
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**and here is the reliant CSS sections (or so I believe)**

```
.logo {
display: block;
text-indent: -9999px;
text-transform: capitalize;
background: url(../images/menu.png) no-repeat;
height: 120px;
}
#menulink {
 display: none;
}
.sidebar {
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: 213px;
/**CODE - background: url(../images/sidebarBg.png); - here**/

float: left;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}

/**  MENU  **/



ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 display: none;
list-style: none;
background: url(../images/sidebarBg.png);
}

ul li {
background: url(../images/listBg.png) bottom no-repeat;
text-indent: 50px;
}

ul li a {
color: white;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 21px;
width: 170px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #191b20;
position:relative;
}
ul li:hover {
background: url(../images/listBgGreen.png) no-repeat;
}

ul li a:hover, ul li:hover a {
color: #FFF;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #547829;
}

ul li a.dashboard {
background: url(../images/iconDashboard.png) 25px 50% no-repeat;
}

ul li a.pages {
background: url(../images/iconPages.png) 25px 50% no-repeat;
}

ul li a.media {
background: url(../images/iconMedia.png) 25px 50% no-repeat;
}

ul li a.history {
background: url(../images/iconHistory.png) 25px 50% no-repeat;
}

ul li a.messages {
background: url(../images/iconMessages.png) 25px 50% no-repeat;
}

ul li a.settings {
background: url(../images/iconSettings.png) 25px 50% no-repeat;
}

/**  SUB MENU  **/

ul li ul.submenu {
display: block;
z-index: 500;
top: 0;
}

ul li ul.submenu li {
background: url(../images/subMenuBg.png) bottom no-repeat;
}

ul li ul.submenu li a {
background: none;
padding: 13px;
width: 189px;
}

ul li ul.submenu li.last {
border-bottom: 1px solid #54575b;
background: url(../images/subMenuBg.png) top no-repeat;
}

ul li ul.submenu li.last a {
padding: 12px;
}

ul li:hover ul.submenu li a {
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 black;
}

ul li ul.submenu li:hover {
background: url(../images/subMenuBgHover.png) bottom no-repeat;
}

/**  PIPS  **/

.pip {
display: block;
background: url(../images/pipBg.png);
padding: 3px 12px;
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
right: 25px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
text-indent: 0;
font-size: 10px;
border-top: 1px solid #1c1f23;
border-bottom: 1px solid #4c4f56;
border-radius: 30px;
-webkit-border-radius: 30px;
-moz-border-radius: 30px;
}

ul li:hover .pip {
background: url(../images/pipBgHover.png);
border-top: 1px solid #547829;
border-bottom: 1px solid #a4ce6b;

}
```

**If you have any more questions** or need any more information, please just ask. As always, thank you so much for your help.

Henry

**JavaScript Eliment**

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function showOrHide(zap) {
 if (document.getElementById) {
  var abra = document.getElementById(zap).style;
  if (abra.display == "block") {
   abra.display = "none";
   } else {
   abra.display = "block";
  } 
  return false;
  } else {
  return true;
 }
}
</script>
```

**Where do I put the width section into this code?** Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by programmatically changing the background image of the *logo* <div>. First, add an id to the the <div> element:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return showOrHide('menulink');">
    <div class="logo" id="menuImg">TEST IMAGE</div>
</a>
```

Then you are able to change the background image in the menu button's click handler:

```
document.getElementById("menuImg").style.backgroundImage = 
    "url(images/menu_open.png)";    // set this when the menu is opened
document.getElementById("menuImg").style.backgroundImage = 
    "url(images/menu.png)";    // set this when the menu is closed
```

Be aware that the URL to the image must be relative to the html document's path (in opposite to the path set inside the stylesheet).

There's an *onclick* event handler set on the menu link calling the javascript function *showOrHide*. This function is defined in the header of your html document as:

```
function showOrHide(zap) {
 if (document.getElementById) {
  var abra = document.getElementById(zap).style;
  if (abra.display == "block") {
   abra.display = "none";
   } else {
   abra.display = "block";
  } 
  return false;
  } else {
  return true;
 }
}
```

At the moment this function is only used for opening and closing the menu so you could change the background image directly in this function:

```
function showOrHide(zap) {
 if (document.getElementById) {
  var abra = document.getElementById(zap).style;
  if (abra.display == "block") {   // menu is currently visible
   abra.display = "none";          // hide the menu
   document.getElementById("menuImg").style.backgroundImage = 
        "url(images/menu.png)";    // set this when the menu is closed
   } else {                        // menu is currently hidden
   abra.display = "block";         // show the menu
   document.getElementById("menuImg").style.backgroundImage = 
        "url(images/menu_open.png)";    // set this when the menu is opened
  } 
  return false;
  } else {
  return true;
 }
}
```

If you're planning to use *showOrHide* for other elements of your page to close and open, you have to redesign the code.

---

At the moment the menu also opens when you click to the right of the menu image. This happens because the *sidebar* <div>'s width is set to 213px but the image is only 40px wide. You could get around this by also changing the <div>'s width when you change the background image.
Change the initial stylesheet value to 40px:

```
.sidebar {
    ...
    width: 40px;
    ...
}
```

add an id to the *sidebar*:

```
<div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
```

and change the width by script code:

```
document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = 
    "213px";    // set this when menu is opened
document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = 
    "40px";    // set this when menu is closed
```

Insert these statements in *showOrHide* just below the corresponding background image codes.

Comment: I now described what to do in more detail. If this doesn't help you out, please tell what exactly you're struggling with.

Comment: ahh ok, let me have a look, 2 mins

Comment: please see newly added javascript section. Where am I placing the new script code?

Comment: ^^^ BTW its just the widths I am looking to change now, as you pointed out. The menu works great except from this, take a look at file:///C:/Users/Henry/Desktop/MENUs/2/index.html

Comment: At the moment you are mixing code with and without the use of jQuery. To have clearer code I would not suggest to do so. If you like to I could adopt my code above to show how this is all done in your jQuery click handler (which is much simpler as my example above).
But I strongly suggest that you stay with jQuery for your complete application.